# How to read “Date” (Day Date MMM YYY)value from “Excel” and send that value into “Date picker” using “Selenium WebDriver” for customise calendar

Tags: selenium-webdriver, data-driven-tests, data-driven

[This html code for calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Hkz.png) 
[This is calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Saxo6.png) 
I need to set date from excel sheet ,but in this calendar I need to set day and month and year

```
driver.findElement(By.id("departureDate")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("departureDate")).sendKeys(depDate);

//  String depDate =reader.getCellData("Sheet1","DepatureDate",2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Date selection depend on html elements in this case we can store string value as month and year like "September 2020" and day as "12" and by apachi poi we can reader this from excel and store variables in test class and use in tests